# TypeError: (0 , .....) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js, themes

I'm building a next.js application with Material-ui.
I am trying to apply material-ui to my project.

I copied the `_app.js , _document.js , theme.js` from the official GitHub page.

All of the files are in the same folder `pages`.
BUT when running the app it appears this error that I don't understand.

```
TypeError: (0 , _material_ui_core_styles__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createTheme) is not a function
    at Object../pages/theme.js (C:\Users\micor\OneDrive\Documents\React\Proyectos React\nextMaterial\my-app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:193:84)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\micor\OneDrive\Documents\React\Proyectos React\nextMaterial\my-app\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at Object../pages/_document.js (C:\Users\micor\OneDrive\Documents\React\Proyectos React\nextMaterial\my-app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:32:64)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\micor\OneDrive\Documents\React\Proyectos React\nextMaterial\my-app\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (C:\Users\micor\OneDrive\Documents\React\Proyectos React\nextMaterial\my-app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:395:52)
    at C:\Users\micor\OneDrive\Documents\React\Proyectos React\nextMaterial\my-app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:396:321
    at Function.__webpack_require__.X (C:\Users\micor\OneDrive\Documents\React\Proyectos React\nextMaterial\my-app\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:108:21)
    at C:\Users\micor\OneDrive\Documents\React\Proyectos React\nextMaterial\my-app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:396:47
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\micor\OneDrive\Documents\React\Proyectos React\nextMaterial\my-app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:399:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
```

I will leave the code down bellow

_document.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/styles';
import createEmotionServer from '@emotion/server/create-instance';
import theme from './theme';

const getCache = () => {
  const cache = createCache({ key: 'css', prepend: true });
  cache.compat = true;

  return cache;
};

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          {/* PWA primary color */}
          <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with static-site generation (SSG).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Resolution order
  //
  // On the server:
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. document.getInitialProps
  // 4. app.render
  // 5. page.render
  // 6. document.render
  //
  // On the server with error:
  // 1. document.getInitialProps
  // 2. app.render
  // 3. page.render
  // 4. document.render
  //
  // On the client
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. app.render
  // 4. page.render

  // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  const cache = getCache();
  const { extractCriticalToChunks } = createEmotionServer(cache);

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
      // Take precedence over the CacheProvider in our custom _app.js
      enhanceComponent: (Component) => (props) =>
        (
          <CacheProvider value={cache}>
            <Component {...props} />
          </CacheProvider>
        ),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
  const emotionStyles = extractCriticalToChunks(initialProps.html);
  const emotionStyleTags = emotionStyles.styles.map((style) => (
    <style
      data-emotion={`${style.key} ${style.ids.join(' ')}`}
      key={style.key}
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: style.css }}
    />
  ));

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement(),
      ...emotionStyleTags,
    ],
  };
};
```

_app.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';
import theme from './theme';

export const cache = createCache({ key: 'css', prepend: true });

export default function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <CacheProvider value={cache}>
      <Head>
        <title>My page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

and final theme.js

```
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { red } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

// Create a theme instance.
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#556cd6',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#19857b',
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400,
    },
    background: {
      default: '#fff',
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a theme you want to use createMuiTheme (https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/)

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#556cd6',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#19857b',
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400,
    },
    background: {
      default: '#fff',
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you.. So when I want to create a theme I use <MuiTheme > and when DO I use <createTheme>

Comment: you import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';